# Run-time error '1004': Copy method of Range class failed Excel 2013 when adding a new pivot table

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting the error specified in the title of this issue when trying to copy and paste some columns (and it's data) to a new workbook.
The code below used to work till the moment when I add a new sheet with a new pivot table in my workbook, and I don't know the reason:

```
Sub ExtractData_2()

  Workbooks.Add
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\extract_Fcst" & ".csv", 6
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Forecast Enrichment").Activate

  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Forecast Enrichment").Range("E:S").Copy Destination:=Workbooks("extract_Fcst.csv").Sheets(1).Range("A:O")

  Workbooks("extract_Fcst.csv").Sheets(1).Range("A:O").EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Does anybody have any idea to how to solve that problem? I have tried a lot of different solutions found in google but any of it works!

Comment: Try omitting the `Destination:=...` from the `.Copy` statement, let's see if the `Copy` fails on its own.

Comment: are you saying that a pivot now exists in your `Forecast Enrichment` sheet whereas before it did not?

Comment: Try what David is suggesting, but I would also recommend this: "Dim myWB As Workbook    Set myWB = Workbooks.Add() myWB.SaveAs........" Also, the Activate statement is unnecessary.

Comment: I also don't see anything in this code that "adds" a new Pivot Table. Are you attempting to *copy* a pivot table from one file to another?

Comment: What I mean with adding a new pivot table is that this issue with VB started to happen when manually I inserted a pivot table sourcing from the sheet where I want to copy to another workbook in a new sheet inside the original workbook. Teorically it doesn't have any relation but I traced when the error started to appear and it was suddenly after that step!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use object variables and assign properly, then break up your copy/Destination to see whether the error raises on the Copy or the Paste, as follows:

```
Sub ExtractData_2()

  Dim csvWorkbook as Workbook

  Set csvWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
  csvWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\extract_Fcst" & ".csv", 6

  ' Unnecessary to "Activate" the sheet...", so you can delete this:
  ' ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Forecast Enrichment").Activate

  'Try using copy/paste as separate statements to see where the failure may occur
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Forecast Enrichment").Range("E:S").Copy
  csvWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Select
  csvWorkbook.Sheets(1).Paste

  csvWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A:O").EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub
```

If it still raises the error, let me know which line it happens.

Comment: Hi; I tried your code but it doesn't accept the "Paste". Instead I tried with "PasteSpecial" but I get a new error "PasteSpecial method of Range class failed". But surprisingly it creates the new .csv with the desired copy.

Comment: Try revised answer using the `Paste` method.

Comment: It still doesn't work! It gives me the same error about "Paste method"

Comment: Check the value of `ThisWorkbook.Path`. If this is a null string, then I believe the `csvWorkbook` will be created as Read Only, which will prevent you from pasting.